# HTML, CSS responsive fluid layout elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm searching how to get responsive height, I mean I have the element.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
   <div style="width: 50%; float: left;"><input style="width: 100%; height: 20px" /></div>
</div>
```

So when I'm re-sizing the browser I wanna scale elements height proportionally to width, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krLf0cbc/7/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="inner">

<input class="input"/>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
}
.input
{
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I think the padding might get in the way. Still, it can work with position:absolute for the child element. I'd add that to the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need to achieve with you current markup but generally you can propotionally change element height with padding property. If padding is set with %, its calculation is based on the element width. However, the contents of the element needs to be absolutely positioned if you use padding.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwt9s5sb/1/

```
.parent {
padding-bottom: 30%;
background: green;
position: relative;}

.child {
position: absolute;}
```